# change value of parameter for my function from another function with objective c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, while-loop

I'm beginner on ios, i have two button, btn1 and btn2.

`function1`: i use this function for my button1, when click on it i have insturcion to do.

`function2`: i use this function for my button2, when click on it i want to change `globalVar` to 1 to stop the loop(`while`) of `function1`.

```
-(IBAction)function1
{

while ( globalVar==0 )
{
    //instruction
}

}

-(IBAction)function2
{
globalVar = 1;
}
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have your while loop running asynchronously in the background:

```
-(IBAction)function1
{
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("loopy-loop-background-queue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void) {

        while ( globalVar==0 )
        {
            //instruction
            _globalCount++;

            if( (_globalCount % 10) == 0)
            {
                [self performSelector:@selector(updateDisplay:)];
            }
        }

    });
}
```

Just remember to put any UI updates back onto the main queue:

```
-(void)updateDisplay:(id)sender
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

        self.outletTimerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _globalCount];
        [self.outletTimerLabel setNeedsDisplay];

    });
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but the while loop doesn't stop when i click on button2.

Comment: I don't see how that works; the `while ( globalVar==0 )` means that loop will only ever be entered once (depending on what else modifies `globalVar`)?

Answer (score 2):

That won't work as you are blocking the UI thread with:

```
while ( globalVar == 0 )    // I assume you meant == and not =
{
    //instruction
}
```

as no UI events can be processed.

Tell us what you actually want to do and I can perhaps provide more of a solution.

Comment: ok, i have uipickerview infinity loop, and i want to stoped it when i click on other button

Comment: @amineamine As I mentioned you cannot introduce infinite loops into event-based systems like Cocoa(Touch).

Comment: then i should use timer?

Comment: @amineamine It depends what you are doing; please provide more detail.

Comment: thank you for your help my freind i foud the solution you can look bellow :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
-(IBAction)function1
{


   NSRunLoop *theRL = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
   while ( globalVar==0 && [theRL runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]])
   {
       //instruction
   }

}

-(IBAction)function2
{
globalVar = 1;
}
```

Comment: yeah i think spinning the runloop would "do it", but it really isn't ideal.

Comment: yes it work but i add `NSLog(@"TOTO");` inside the loop (`while`), does not show me in real-time the (TOTO) in the log. but when i stop the loop it appears.

Answer (score 0):

finally i found the solution of my problem.the code bellow is the solution

```
- (IBAction)function1
{

    dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("loopy-loop-background-queue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^(void) {

        while ( _globalVar==0 )
        {
            //instruction
            _globalCount++;
            NSLog(@"aaa");

            if( (_globalCount % 10) == 0)
            {
                [self performSelector:@selector(function2)];
            }
        }

    });
}

-(IBAction)function2
{
    if (_stop!=0)
    {
        _globalVar=1;
    }
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
    {

        self.outletTimerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", _globalCount];
        [self.outletTimerLabel setNeedsDisplay];

    });
}

-(IBAction)function3
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                   {

                       _stop=1;

                   });
}
```

Comment: That's horrible.  I pity your users.  Yes you should use a timer.

Answer (score -2):

```
-(IBAction)function1
{

    while ( globalVar==0 )
    {
      //instruction
    }

}

-(IBAction)function2
{
   globalVar = 1;
   [self function1]; // goto
}
```